# Need to implement 'Call End' feature in my app

Tags: android, telephonymanager, android-phone-call

I am developing a "DemoApp" in which i've made a 'End Call' button, when any incoming call comes to my phone i just received it by using default dialer app and than i open my "DemoApp" and when i press the 'End Call' button, i just want to end the incoming call.

I've successfully accomplished 'End Call' feature by following code :

```
private boolean declinePhone() {
    try {
        String serviceManagerName = "android.os.ServiceManager";
        String serviceManagerNativeName = "android.os.ServiceManagerNative";
        String telephonyName = "com.android.internal.telephony.ITelephony";
        Class<?> telephonyClass;
        Class<?> telephonyStubClass;
        Class<?> serviceManagerClass;
        Class<?> serviceManagerNativeClass;
        Method telephonyEndCall;
        Object telephonyObject;
        Object serviceManagerObject;
        telephonyClass = Class.forName(telephonyName);
        telephonyStubClass = telephonyClass.getClasses()[0];
        serviceManagerClass = Class.forName(serviceManagerName);
        serviceManagerNativeClass = Class.forName(serviceManagerNativeName);
        Method getService = // getDefaults[29];
                serviceManagerClass.getMethod("getService", String.class);
        Method tempInterfaceMethod = serviceManagerNativeClass.getMethod("asInterface", IBinder.class);
        Binder tmpBinder = new Binder();
        tmpBinder.attachInterface(null, "fake");
        serviceManagerObject = tempInterfaceMethod.invoke(null, tmpBinder);
        IBinder retbinder = (IBinder) getService.invoke(serviceManagerObject, "phone");
        Method serviceMethod = telephonyStubClass.getMethod("asInterface", IBinder.class);
        telephonyObject = serviceMethod.invoke(null, retbinder);
        telephonyEndCall = telephonyClass.getMethod("endCall");
        telephonyEndCall.invoke(telephonyObject);
        return true;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.d("unable", "msg cant dissconect call....");
    }
    return false;
}
```

I just want to know whether i can achieve this by using "ConnectionService" API. I've studied 'https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/telecom/selfManaged' this article it is giving me a solution to develop my own 'Dialer App' but i do not want to make my own dialer.

Answer (score 0):

Exactly as you suspected there are two options:

1. Create a full-blown calling app (your own custom in-call UI, your
   own handling of call notifications, etc.) and then you can use the
   nice `Call.disconnect()` API
2. Use the hack code you posted.